# Syntax check passes but uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

Guys what else could be wrong when jshint, esprima all passes the code but chrome throws this error ? I am having a hard time figuring out.

P.S : Sorry I can't really share the code as I am not supposed to and I have to share the whole app code.

Comment: Geez, at least show us the line or half-dozen surrounding lines.

Comment: problem is it doesn't show where the error is. Otherwise I would have shared at least that part. If it showed then I would have solved it maybe

Answer (score -1):

If you can't share the code, it will be hard for anyone to tell you what is wrong.

One thing you can do is simplify your code down to a concise test case, using the "divide and conquer" technique. Just start taking out big chunks of code, and keep repeating until one of the following happens:

- The error goes away. This means the problem was in the last chunk of code you deleted. Put that code back in and take out only part of it and test again. Repeat this as needed.
- Some *other* error crops up that wasn't there originally. Put back the last deleted chunk and either try deleting only a part of it, or deleting something else.
- The error remains, but now there is so little code left that you will either see what the problem is, or else you won't have a problem posting it here for help. Once you have it down to a minimal test case like this, you can start renaming variables and functions so that it no longer reveals any company secrets.

Comment: Hmm... A downvote for what I thought was a helpful post explaining how to use "divide and conquer" for someone who may not be familiar with the technique? If there was a problem with what I wrote, I would appreciate knowing the specifics of what is wrong so I can do better. Thanks!